# Como eu poderia resolver esta questão utilizando dicionários em Python?

Tags: python

Faça um programa que leia duas strings do teclado e informe:

• Os caracteres do primeiro texto que não estão no segundo;

• Os caracteres do segundo texto que não estão no primeiro;

• Os caracteres que estão em ambos os textos;

• O número total de caracteres distintos em ambos os textos.

Exemplo:
Entre com o primeiro texto: wendel

Entre com o segundo texto: alexandre
Caracteres do primeiro texto que não estão no segundo:
w

Caracteres do segundo texto que não estão no primeiro:
r a x

Caracteres em ambos os textos:
e l n d

Numero total de caracteres distintos em ambos os textos: 8

**Ele deu exemplo de como fazer a frequência de caracteres**

```
def contaFrequencia(texto):
    frequencia = {}

    for c in texto:
        if c not in frequencia:
            frequencia[c] = 0

        frequencia[c] = frequencia[c] + 1
    return frequencia

if __name__ == "__main__":
    texto = input('Entre com um texto: ')
    freqs = contaFrequencia(texto)

    print('Frequência de caracteres:')
    for c in freqs.keys():
        print('%s : %s ' % (c, freqs[c]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver esse problema é utilizando [conjuntos](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).
Um objeto conjunto é uma coleção não ordenada de objetos hasheáveis distintos, não há repetição de elementos. Usos comuns incluem testes de associação, remover duplicatas de uma sequência e computar operações matemáticas tais como interseção, união, diferença e diferença simétrica.

Converta cada strings de entrada em um conjunto de caracteres e aplique os operadores relacionais para obter as informações desejadas:

- Para saber os caracteres do primeiro texto que não estão no segundo faça a [diferença](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) entre `texto1` e `texto2`.
- Para saber os caracteres do segundo texto que não estão no primeiro faça a diferença entre `texto2` e `texto1`.
- Para saber os caracteres que estão em ambos os textos faça a [intercessão](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) entre os dois textos.
- Para saber o número total de caracteres distintos em ambos os textos faça a [união](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) entre os dois conjuntos e [meça o comprimento](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#len) do resultado.

```python
texto1 = "wendel"#input('Entre com um texto: ')
texto2 = "alexandre"#input('Entre com outro texto: ')

#Converte as entradas em conjuntos.
s1 = set(texto1)
s2 = set(texto2)

r1 = s1 - s2      #Os caracteres do primeiro texto que não estão no segundo.
r2 = s2 - s1      #Os caracteres do segundo texto que não estão no primeiro.
r3 = s1 & s2      #Os caracteres que estão em ambos os textos.
r4 = len(s1 | s2) #O número total de caracteres distintos em ambos os textos.

print(f'Os caracteres do primeiro texto que não estão no segundo:\n {r1}')
print(f'Os caracteres do segundo texto que não estão no primeiro:\n {r2}')
print(f'Os caracteres que estão em ambos os textos:\n {r3}')
print(f'O número total de caracteres distintos em ambos os textos:\n {r4}')
```

Resultando:

```
Os caracteres do primeiro texto que não estão no segundo:
 {'w'}
Os caracteres do segundo texto que não estão no primeiro:
 {'a', 'x', 'r'}
Os caracteres que estão em ambos os textos:
 {'n', 'e', 'd', 'l'}
O número total de caracteres distintos em ambos os textos:
 8
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/a5h5PB)</sup>